# Is it possible use SQL Server Service Broker for send data to a service?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, service-broker

I want to send data to a service (NOT WS) that runs on a local machine when a new row appears in a table. Is it possible to do this with triggers, queue and service broker?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? And what is "SQL Service Broker"?

Comment: sorry my dbms is sql server 2014 service broker is this https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You could create a trigger on your table that sends a message to a queue (at least with the PK of the table, possibly more information) and your application can at a later point call `receive` on the queue to see if there is anything to do. The devil is in the details, but that's a high-level architectural description.

Comment: ok thanks, so service broker it isn't used just for exchanging data between database

Comment: Service Broker is just a way to send messages to a queue. What those messages contain and what you do with them is up to you.